# vim gq speed up the artificial new line to add first

Tags: vim

To reindent this below:

```
 * - P2P.32-1
   - Identification des retards de rotoemant par rapport aux conditions de huitmots (calculé sur la base de la date de pièce)
 * - P2P.32-2
   - Identification des rotoemants réalisés en retard par rapport aux conditions de huitmots (calculé sur la base de la date de saisie)
 * - P2P.33
```

to this:

```
 * - P2P.32-1
   - Identification des retards de rotoemant par rapport aux conditions de huitmots
     (calculé sur la base de la date de pièce)
 * - P2P.32-2
   - Identification des rotoemants réalisés en retard par rapport aux conditions de
     huitmots (calculé sur la base de la date de saisie)
 * - P2P.33
```

I need to do the following keystroks: first to add an empty line with `A <return>`

```
 * - P2P.32-1
   - Identification des retards de rotoemant par rapport aux conditions de huitmots (calculé sur la base de la date de pièce)
 ^ # cursor here 
 * - P2P.32-2
```

so then I get this

```
 * - P2P.32-1
   - Identification des retards de rotoemant par rapport aux conditions de huitmots (calculé sur la base de la date de pièce)

 * - P2P.32-2
```

Then I have to `<excape>k` to go back to the line Identification, and only then I can do a "`gq`" then "`j`" to go down and "`dd`" to remove the empty line

```
 * - P2P.32-1
   - Identification des retards de rotoemant par rapport aux conditions de huitmots
     (calculé sur la base de la date de pièce)
 * - P2P.32-2
```

So at the end I need: "`A<return><escape>kgqjdd`"

Is there a shorter path ?

Note: I have a `:set tw=88`

Comment: `A<return>` is the same as `o`. But I think you don't need this artificial empty line at all. Try `gq$` — i.e. "format only the current line to the end of the line".

Comment: No, you don't need to do all that dance at all. Plain `gq<motion>` or `gq` on a visual selection will do what you want.

Comment: "*visual selection*", Oh, BTW, `Vgq` nice!